# Can't pickle instance method using Pool.map(), but I have no instance method

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, pool

I'm trying to use the `multiprocessing.Pool` object to run some database queries in parallel. I'm using MySQLdb.

I have some module-level functions where I define queries to run, like this:

```
def check_foo(cursor, table):
    query = "(some query)"
    cursor.execute(query)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    return len(results) == 0
```

These functions are collected when the program is run, like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    check_functions = [v for k, v in globals().items()
                             if k.startswith('check_') and callable(v)]
```

I also have a module-level function that runs a particular check function on a list of tables:

```
def run_check_on_all((tables, cursor, f)):
    return [f(cursor, table) for table in tables]
```

I want to have one worker process for each check function that will call `run_check_on_all` for that function. Here's my attempt to do that:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(len(check_functions))
    cursors = [conn.cursor() for i in range(len(check_functions))]

    print "Running {0} check(s)...".format(len(check_functions))
    table_lists = [table_list] * len(check_functions)
    all_results = pool.map(run_check_on_all, zip(table_lists, cursors, check_functions))
```

When I attempt to run this, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Python2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Python2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 484, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Python2.6/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 225, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed
```

As you can (hopefully) see, nothing involved in the call to `pool.map` is an instance method. `run_check_on_all` and each of the `check_functions` are module-level functions. `table_lists` is a list of lists of strings. `cursors` is a list of MySQLdb cursor objects.

I thought maybe it had to do with calling the cursor objects' instance methods in the check functions, but I replaced them with dummy functions like this

```
def check_foo(cursor, table):
    print "hello"
```

and still no luck.

Where is the instance method that the error is referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you attempt to pass database cursor objects between processes. Each process must create a connection to the database, and create a cursor on that connection.